# Why is my "Add-in Manager" menu disabled in VisualStudio 2010 (Ultimate)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why is my "Add-in Manager" menu disabled in VisualStudio 2010 (Ultimate)
How can I enable it?

Comment: Have you started Visual Studio in safe mode? Check the comment line options of your shortcut you used to start VS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options and then Environment->Add-in/Macro Security. Make sure "Allow Add-in components to load" is checked.